# edit metadata in a bulk photo upload section?

Tags: image, grouped-list, upload, bulk

I'm working on a production system with a feature for uploading ambiance images & tagging those images.
The current UI flow for uploading & tagging three images isn't good enough when 100+ ambiance images are required (per day).

I'm looking for a solution to bulk edit images metadata AND visually group those photos.

- All the ambiance images has 3 properties (2 properties are in "levels")
- There are images with some of the same properties
- At least one property has to be different than the other images.

for example:

```
1st level group name: "Color" >>
    2nd level group name: "Color, Green" >>
       #1 image: Color, Green, Number1         
       #2 image: Color, Green, Number2
       #3 image: Color, Green, Number3
       #4 image: Neutral, Number1    
   2nd level group name: "Color, Blue" >>
       #1 image: Color, Blue, Number1         
       #2 image: Color, Blue, Number2
       #3 image: Color, Blue, Number3 
       #4 image: Neutral, Number1
```

There are images that fits all / most of the groups
for example - the last image.

```
#1 image: Neutral, Number1 - will fit ALL groups
```

Our users upload 1 image in the current UI, attaching the image's 1st level tag+ 2nd level tag + number tag.

Comment: What are your criteria for an "optimized" solution? I would suggest that a UI very closely tied to the information architecture you presented above would equate to the simplest means to achieve a responsive and maintainable tool that conveys its message well to most Users. You could do tons on top of that, whether it optimizes or wastes time/money is debatable/testable.

Comment: By "optimized," I mean - 
the best solution for multi-image upload & multi-image tag tasks.
Until now, the current UI was "enough", but as our company grows - more images are needed - the "simple" 3 images uploading & tagging flow isn't good enough when 100+ images uploading & tagging required (per day).
If you have any reference for image uploading and metadata tagging feature, it will help me a lot.
Thank you :)